# Does it take less time to load the image if only a fraction of its was used on a web page?

Tags: html, css, performance, browser

It has come to my mind, imagine you have a **2x2 grid** container with each grid item as a div. Now you will use one image e.g., only the top-left fraction of the image for the first div, top-right for the second div. Does it the same as loading the image four times from the source? Does loading a fraction take less time?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Either the entire image is loaded, or it is not loaded at all. There is no way in the HTTP specification to request only a portion of an image.

However, if you use (a part of) the image in multiple places on the page, the image gets loaded only once.